# GRAILS Check if atleast one of multiple properties is set

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

assuming I have something like this as Domain Class in Grails 2.x

```
class CurrentReading {

    DateTime timestamp
    Sensor sensor
    Integer valueInt
    Boolean valueBool
    Float valueFloat

    static constraints = {
        timestamp blank: false 
        sensor blank: false
    }

}
```

Is there an out of the box GORM / Validation feature that allows me to ensure that exactly one of the properties `valueInt`, `valueFloat` or `valueBool` is set?

I have done some experimenting with `grails install-plugin constraints`, but failed to pass additional domain properties to the custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
static constraints = {
    type inList:['Foo', 'Bar', 'FooBar']
    idStr blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
        def result
        if(obj.type == "FooBar") {
            result = val =~ /[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{8}/
        } else if(['Foo', 'Bar'].contains(obj.type)) {
            result = val =~ /\d+/
        }
        result.matches()
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically writing my own validator? Kind of hard to see, with the example :)